# Extracting lines from perl Nx3 Array

Tags: perl

I want to extract blocks of size 3x3 from an Nx3 array.

```
    foreach (@TotalData){
         print "@{$_}\n";
    }
```

Gives me (as an example):

```
    .
    .
    0.000 22.00 3.791140e+000
    0.100 22.00 2.737532e+000
    0.200 22.00 2.393466e+000
    .
    .
```

Where the dots represent other entries.
I want to place this 3x3 block in its own array. 
How can I extract this?

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Comment: For instance:
        foreach (@TotalData){
                push @BlockArray, \@{$_};
        }

I thought would copy line by line, but when I go to print BlockArray I get emptiness.

Comment: Give us an entire program in the question for us to look at, not just a summary in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do with the blocks?  Maybe you just want a slice of @TotalData (e.g. `@TotalData[4,5,6]` or even `splice(@TotalData, 4, 3)`), maybe you want to loop over it 3 at a time (e.g. with `List::MoreUtils::natatime`); you haven't really given enough information to say.

If you don't mind clearing @TotalData as a side effect:

```
while ( my @block = splice( @TotalData, 0, 3 ) ) {
    # do something with @block (which will have 3 elements,
    # except on the last iteration, where it will have 1-3)
}
```

To only get complete blocks of 3:

```
while ( 3 == ( my @block = splice( @TotalData, 0, 3 ) ) ) {
    # do something with @block (which will have 3 elements)
}
```

Comment: I want to take each block, and print it to its own file. I will then use gnuplot to plot a few different sets of the right most column on the same plot, with the x-axis being the first column, and the middle column being the curve label.

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather sure that [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) has methods for doing just this. In fact, almost this same problem is investigated in the [Conway's Game of Life example](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=Threading&title=PDL%3a%3aThreading#example__conway_s_game_of_life) from the PDL docs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [List::MoreUtils::natatime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List%3a%3aMoreUtils)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );

my @data = (
    [1 .. 3],
    [4 .. 6],
    [7 .. 9],
    ['a' .. 'c'],
    ['d' .. 'f'],
    ['g' .. 'i'],
);

my $it = natatime(3, @data);

while (my @set = $it->()) {
    for my $r ( @set ) {
        print "@$r\n";
    }
    print '-' x 30, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp> ./jj.pl
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
------------------------------
a b c
d e f
g h i
------------------------------
```

Comment: Actually mine is probably overkill, I like `natatime` for taking 3x3 from Nx3. See mine when you want to take ALL the 3x3 from NxM where N and M  are both greater than 3

Comment: All I get from that method is:
          
          
          -----------------------------


          -----------------------------

Comment: Computers are deterministic things¹. If you copied & pasted the script I posted, you should get the output I show above. If you ran some other code, you should show it so we can spot what's wrong with it. **¹** [Quantum::Superpositions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Quantum::Superpositions) notwithstanding.